# encoding issue in powershell search and replace

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm running a powershell script on XML files recursively to search and replace text. The code is working fine with searching and replacing the text. However in certain files there are other languages text like **fréquentes** which is getting changed to **frÃ©quentes** after running the script. I've been using UTF8 encoding in the script. Any pointers on how to retain the encoading?

```
$content| Foreach-Object{$_ -replace 'test1' , 'testing'`
                            -replace 'test2' , 'testing' }| Out-File file.FullName -Encoding utf8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be ignoring the XML file's encoding, which seems to be Latin 1. XML files specify their encoding at the start (or, if they don't, they will be autodetected as UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
```

So it seems to me like you read the content with the correct encoding, but write the file in UTF-8 which doesn't match the declared one.

You could use the XML APIs to change the file, which may be preferable, or simply change your `Out-File` to

```
Out-File -Encoding Default
```

*However*, that can cause the encoding to differ between different computers, so careful with that. I pretty much only use it for files I know are in the system's legacy codepage, or for quick one-off scripts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Changing it to default works.
 My XML file has the below in it and thats why I was trying to use utf8 in the script.
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
Does default mean to use the same encoding which is already there in XML file or to change the XML file to default from utf-8

Comment: `Default` means to use the system's legacy codepage, which is why it's such a bad idea to use it, normally. This encoding only exists to cater for non-Unicode applications, but text files often are in that encoding as well. If the XML file *rightfully* declares to be UTF-8, then the code you posted shouldn't harm anything. Another option to avoid this, if your replacements don't contain non-ASCII characters, would be to just use Default for reading *and* writing. That way everything that's non-ASCII is just passed through (if you use an 8-bit legacy codepage; most do).